# Writing subquery within SUM using values of 1 table

Tags: sql, oracle

Now I have a table and I am trying to calculate for each book_id the total sales in the past 100 days for every day in the past 1 year.

```
book_id location seller daily_sales order_day
 ABC      1        XYZ   100         2017-05-05
 ABC      1        XYZ   120         2017-05-07
 ABC      1        XYZ   40          2017-02-10
 .
 .
 .
```

So what I am trying to expect in the result is:

```
book_id order_day sum
 ABC    2017-05-05 100+40
 ABC    2017-05-07 100+120+40
 ABC    2017-02-10 40
```

For this I wrote a query like this:

```
select book_id, to_char(order_day), 
    SUM(case when order_day between order_day -100 and order_day then daily_sales else 0 end) sum
    FROM bookDetailsTable
    where location = 1 AND ORDER_DAY BETWEEN TO_DATE('20170725','YYYYMMDD') - 359 AND TO_DATE('20170725','YYYYMMDD')
    group by seller, book_id, order_day
```

I guess I am doing wrong and I should write a select statement within the SUM statement to select data for the past 100 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the result with this

```
select  A.book_id, 
        A.order_day,
        (   select sum(b.daily_sales) 
            from bookDetailsTable b 
            where A.book_id = B.book_id 
            and B.order_day between A.order_day -100 and A.order_day
        )
from bookDetailsTable A
where A.order_day between ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate),-12) and trunc(sysdate)
```

If you understand the principle of the query, you should be able to add your other restrictions, like `seller` or `location`

Comment: I should also add at the outer level a where condition like
from bookDetailsTable A WHERE A.order_day between TO_DATE('20170725','YYYYMMDD') - 365 AND TO_DATE('20170725','YYYYMMDD') to limit this within the last 1 year

Comment: Also to get a better understanding, the original query I wrote, what sum will it be calculating?

Comment: the condition `when order_day between order_day -100 and order_day` is always valid for each line. Therefore you will compute the sum of `daily_sales`

Comment: so you mean it will be just computing the sum for the past 100 days. Is there a way to optimize this query? Since I have a lot of rows, doing another select for sum will make this query really slow.

Comment: not for the past 100 days in your query. Nowhere you filter. You just check that for 1 line, the date should be between itself and itself-100 ... therefore, it is always valid. Optimization can be done using index. or maybe try replacing `select` by `select /*+ PARALLEL */`

Comment: for both the select? or just the summation part?

Comment: I cant really say without looking at the structure and the explain plans. sorry. Just try it. With good index, the query should be ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150135/discussion-between-steven-benet-and-user1692342).

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect case for using analytic functions, specifically the SUM() analytic function, along with the windowing clause:

```
WITH bookdetailstable AS (SELECT 'ABC' book_id, 1 LOCATION, 'XYZ' seller, 100 daily_sales, to_date('05/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_day FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'ABC' book_id, 1 LOCATION, 'XYZ' seller, 120 daily_sales, to_date('07/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_day FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'ABC' book_id, 1 LOCATION, 'XYZ' seller, 40 daily_sales, to_date('10/02/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_day FROM dual UNION ALL
                          SELECT 'ABC' book_id, 1 LOCATION, 'XYZ' seller, 600 daily_sales, to_date('10/02/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') order_day FROM dual)
SELECT book_id,
       to_char(order_day, 'yyyy-mm-dd') order_day,
       total_sales_last_100_days
FROM   (SELECT book_id,
               order_day,
               SUM(daily_sales) OVER (PARTITION BY book_id ORDER BY order_day
                                      RANGE BETWEEN 100 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) total_sales_last_100_days
        FROM   bookdetailstable
        where  order_day >= add_months(trunc(sysdate) - 100, -12))
where  order_day >= add_months(trunc(SYSDATE), -12);

BOOK_ID ORDER_DAY  TOTAL_SALES_LAST_100_DAYS
------- ---------- -------------------------
ABC     2016-02-10                        40
ABC     2016-05-05                       140
ABC     2016-05-07                       260
ABC     2017-02-10                       600
```

This simply says get the sum of daily_sales for each book_id (you can think of the `partition by` clause as being similar to the `group by` clause - it simply defines the group of rows the function applies over) ordered by the order_day, looking at the 100 preceding rows and the current row.

If you needed to work out the cumulative sum for specific book_ids based on location (and seller and ....), then you would need to include the extra grouping columns in the partition by clause.

Since you want to restrict the results to the past year, assuming you want the first row to return the count for the past 100 days as well, rather than starting with the current day, you need to include 100 days prior to a year ago. Then you restrict the rows to the year's worth of data you're interested in.

That's because analytic functions work across the data after it's been filtered by the where clause, so if you want to include data from outside the current where clause, you're going to have to look for a way to include those rows and then do the additional filtering later.

Comment: I didn't understand the unions you are doing. I can't see where you are taking for the past 1 year ?

Comment: Also you are hard coding the seller name here.

Comment: Since my database doesn't contain a table called "bookdetailstable" with your data in it, I had to mimic the table, which I did by using a subquery. (If you're not familiar with subquery factoring (aka the with clause aka common table expressions aka CTEs), I highly recommend you research it!). The values are hardcoded because, well, how else was I going to mimic your data?! (Yes, I could have manually created a table, but the insert statements would still have had to have the data hardcoded in them!). You would not need the bookdetailstable subquery, since you already have the table.

Comment: Hmm ok. Also I should add a WHERE condition like this right?
ORDER_DAY between ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate),-12) and trunc(sysdate)

Comment: Would this be sort of a O(N) complexity query? I have about 20 million rows.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the filtering you wanted. Note that I've assumed that for the order_day a year ago, you're still wanting the previous 100 day's worth of sales figures included in the sum.

Comment: I've no idea about O(N) complexities; this query needs to sort and process the data in order to calculate the cumulative sum, but since you need that data being processed, you don't have much choice. You have two solutions presented to you - I suggest you test each one with your data and see which one is most performant.

Comment: Why are we having the condition of date outside the inner query as well? Would't this query basically do a lookup of the table N^2 times?

Comment: Um, no, it goes through the table once. Feel free to look at the execution plan for the query to confirm that.... As for the second where clause, well - if you restricted the data to a year's worth of data and then asked for the sum of 100 previous day's sales, the first day's sum would only include that day's total, since there are no other days before it. So, if you want to get the actual cumulative sum total, you need to include those 100 days in the query containing the analytic function. Then restrict it again to get the year's worth of data you're interested in.